# React For Cycle in SetState

Tags: reactjs, fetch, setstate

Help me please to put for cycle into the setState in the fetch

```
fetch(ip + '/stats', {
    method: "GET",
})
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    this.setState({ 
        variable: {
             datasets: [{
                 data: [
                        data[0],
                        data[1],
                        data[2],
                        data[3],
                        data[4],
                        data[5],
                    ],
                }]
            }
        })
    }
})
```

But i have a for of items in the data

But when I want to insert for into this, like that

```
fetch(ip + '/stats', {
    method: "GET",
})
.then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
})
.then(data => {
    this.setState({ 
        variable: {
             datasets: [{
                 data: [
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        data[i],
                    }
                    ],
                }]
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I got an error 'Parsing error: Unexpected token'

Help me please. How to cycle in the setState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your `data` variable and then set it as state variable, like this:

```
.then(data => {
    let dataArr = [];

    for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        dataArr.push(data[i]);

    this.setState({variable: {datasets: [{data: dataArr}]}});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write as:

```
// { data } is shortcut for { data: data }
this.setState({ variable: { datasets: [{ data }] } })
```

if you actually need to create a new array from data array:

```
// [...myArr]: this spreads myArr values into a new array
this.setState({ variable: { datasets: [{ data: [...data] }] } })
```